# Scan open network ports in android

Tags: android, networking

Is there a way to to scan open network ports thru android? For example behind a firewall that blocks me from sending UDP packets thru certain ports. So is there a way to scan which ports are not blocked to the internet by the firewalls? Maybe a terminal application or in a  programmatical way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible but it's far from easy.
You can open sockets and use standard TCP networking. Scanning for ports is another thing altogether tho.